# How do I create a timeline chart which shows multiple events? Eg. Metallica Band members timeline on wiki

Tags: excel, charts, timeline

How do I create a timeline chart which shows multiple events? Eg. Metallica Band members timeline on wiki ?  where it shows the multiple band members and their durations.

Technologies to be used : Microsoft Office primarily. Any exotic technology where the learning curve isn't too much to do this stuff, should also be fine?

[image]

Comment: An example of exotic technology without big learning curve is Google Charts: Time Line. https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline.

Comment: Within 10 days this question is 6x upvoted and it has 4 favorite badges. Obviously people disagree to close these types of questions. Me too. The question is clearly defined, the attached picture is very useful and based on upvotes people want an answer.

Comment: I found a good article that seems to cover all the details: https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-excel

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A Stacked bar chart should suffice:

Setup data as follows

```
Name    Start       End         Duration (End - Start)
Fred    1/01/1981   1/06/1985    1612   
Bill    1/07/1985   1/11/2000    5602  
Joe     1/01/1980   1/12/2001    8005  
Jim     1/03/1999   1/01/2000    306
```

1. Plot `Start` and `Duration` as a stacked bar chart
2. Set the `X-Axis minimum` to the desired start date
3. Set the `Fill` Colour of the`start` range to `no fill`
4. Set the `Fill` of individual bars to suit

(example prepared in Excel 2010)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes stacked bar chart did the trick, though the data needed to be set up differently. I will accept the answer, as it showed me the direction, but will also put up a version below for somebody else's benefit!

Comment: @Chris Neilsen, is there a macro or something to get the data in your presented way?

Comment: Is it possible to show the stacks in one line. (The start of one event is on ending of previous) ?

Comment: Here is an old tutorial showing how to do the Gantt Chart https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oD50HSBBBI

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the earlier comment, stacked bar chart does the trick, though the data needs to be setup differently.(See image below)

Duration  column = End - Start

1. Once done, plot your stacked bar chart using the entire data.
2. Mark start and end range to no fill.
3. Right click on the X Axis and change Axis options manually. (This did cause me some issues, till I realized I couldn't manipulate them to enter dates, :) yeah I am newbie, excel masters! :))

[image]

Comment: How did you get the data in that format?