# Create timeline in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, timeline

I am trying to create timelines in Excel as simple product roadmaps.

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191515/how-do-i-create-a-timeline-chart-in-excel) from a few years ago and it pointed me in the right direction.

Here's what I've managed so far:
[Timeline test 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RePL4.jpg)

Durations for each phase are in months.

The display is ok, but I can't get the x-axis configured properly to show the correct dates. Also, the two product timelines should start at different dates, as shown in the image.

I suspect its not so difficult to do what I want, but Excel doesn't make it obvious how to do so.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: For me to comment on your code, you need to post your code!! as a text file. "as shown in the image" >> but the bars do not show it, only the small text at the top does... SHOWN was a word that directed me to look at the bars-- confusion.

Comment: Looks like you need to format the axis of the chart

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reasonable approximation of this by

(1) Including the start date as an additional time duration

(2) Converting the other time durations to days by mutiplying by 30.4... (i.e. 365.25/12)

This gives you a timeline starting from 1/1/1900.

(3) Plot this on a horizontal bar chart as before.

(4) Format the first series to have no fill and no border.

(5) Format the x-axis to have the vertical axis crossing as the start date (say 15/1/15), the major tick mark division as 365.25, the number format as YY/MM and the maximum as whatever you want the finish date to be (say 15/1/25)

The data looks like this

[image]

and the plot like this

[image]