# Excel: How to create a Gantt Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, stack

Given the following data set:

```
 Request    starttime   Duration (ms)
 1  00.000  222
 2  00.005  257
 3  00.001  270
 4  00.003  299
 5  00.292  198
 6  00.327  199
 7  00.318  319
 8  00.333  451
 9  00.511  323
```

I need to draw an overlapping bar graph, something akin to this overlapping bar graph (from google):

[image]

However, when I try to draw the bar chart in mac excel, excel overloads the y-axis with request count and start time, rather than making start time and duration as both applied to the x-axis.

[image]

In short, the y-axis is the request number and the x-axis the both the start time and duration.  Is there a way in excel to shift the bars to the starting time listed in the dataset?

SOLUTION: 
After learning how to draw Gantt Chart in excel, the resulting chart looks great.
[image]

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870974/445425)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I was going to sarcastically say "use MS Project",  The linked question even more so!

Comment: Your sample chart is called a gantt chart. So search keywords `excel gantt chart` will help.

Comment: @AxelRichter, Good answer. Make your comment as the answer and I'll accept as such. Your comment falls under "give him a fish, feed him for a day, teach him how to fish, feed him for life."  https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-excel. Thanks all.