# How to create a Gantt Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, gantt-chart

I have set of data that shows a few different things: worker #, task #, task start time, and task finish time. The data looks a little something like this.

```
worker #      task#       start time       finish time
1             task 1      3:30             3:49
1             task 2      3:30             7:35
2             task 3      3:30             4:17
2             task 4      4:43             5:59
2             task 5      6:13             6:37
3             task 6      3:30             5:26
3             task 7      5:46             7:39
```

As you'll notice, task 1 and 2 are supposedly started by worker 1 at the same time. If anyone has an idea how to get around this then that'd be appreciated but otherwise **I am more concerned about trying to come up with a way to transform this data into a gantt chart by time interval.** I rounded all of the time stamps to the nearest 15 minute mark. I would like my gantt chart to look like this below.

```
Time    3:30    3:45    4:00    4:15    4:30    4:45    5:00    5:15    5:30    5:45    6:00    6:15    6:30    6:45    7:00    7:15    7:30
Worker1 task1   task2   task2   task2   task2   task2   task2   task2   task2   task2  
Worker2 task3   task3   task3                   task4   task4   task4   task4   task4           task5
Worker3 task 6  task6   task6   task6   task6   task6   task6   task6           task7   task7   task7   task7   task7   task7   task7   task7
```

**My Approach**

I was able to come up with a formula that populates the time interval that the task is being performed in so I've made a gantt chart that looks like the below.

[Not consolidated Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgsB1.png)

The formula is these cells is as follows

```
=IF('Start Time'='time interval','task #',IF(AND('Start Time'<'next time interval','Finish Time'>'next time interval'),'task #',""))
```

I went about it this way because I figured there would be a way to then scrunch everything so that it's broken out by worker number instead of task number but instead I've gotten stuck in coming up with a formula to do so.

Comment: Possibly useful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770178/excel-how-to-create-a-gantt-chart-in-excel) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870974/445425)

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I will see if this works.